# How to use searchBar in the ionic V1

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating a building survey application, and I'm having a hard time using ionic V1 ion-search.

Has anyone done anything similar on ionic 1? I accept any help.

This is my code

```
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
<form id="prDios-form2" class="list">
    <label class="item item-input" id="prDios-search2">
      <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Localizar">
    </label>
  </form>
<div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 0px;"></div>
<ion-list id="prDios-list2">
  <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right royal" id="prDios-list-item7" ui-sref="tabsController.abaete()">
    <img src="img/ZrWSoK1zRIi2V8WMALas_Abaete.JPG">
    <h2royal>Abaeté
      <p>Rua Andira</p>
      <i class="icon ion-map"></i>
    </h2royal>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. There is no `<ion-search>` directive for ionic v1. Ionic doesn't provide one.

As for searching, you can make a custom search form and implement it similarly to `<ion-search>`.

you will need. a form with a text input(your prDios-form2 with the input will do. add ng-model and ng-change for the input), `<ion-list>` with ng-repeat, `<ion-infinite-scroll>` to add more results when scrolled to the bottom.

you can use the ng-change attribute of the input to look for changes, call an api with the ng-model value of the text field.

It is possible, because i have implemented it. Attaching a picture of the custom ion search i created.

[image]

Hope I was of some help. Cheers!!!